# Chakra ui modal not working on button click

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to use chakra ui modal in my app. but  this modal is not showing , when I directly pass true to to isOpen  .its showing .but when i pass isOpen Disclosure  it is not working. when I check the react dev tools. the value of isOpen is changed to true on the button click. but the popup is not coming

```
import {
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  ModalCloseButton,
  Button,
  useDisclosure,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
function Home() {
  const {isOpen,onOpen,onClose} = useDisclosure()

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>
            {/* <Lorem count={2} /> */}
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme='blue' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant='ghost'>Secondary Action</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

export default Home

Comment: I have the same issue (